# Finding the general solution of the differential equation $\left[ 1+\left( x+y\right)^2\right]dx+\left[1+x(x+y)\right]dy=0 $.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the general solution of $\left[ 1+\left( x+y\right)^2\right]dx+\left[1+x(x+y)\right]dy $.

I am stuck at this problem. Here is my solution:

Let $u=x+y$

$du=dx+dy$

$dy=du-dx$

$\left(1+u^2 \right)dx+\left(1+ux\right)(du-dx)=0$

$\left(u^2-ux\right)dx+(1+ux)du=0$

Let $x=uz; dx=udz+zdu$

$\left(u^2-u^2z \right)(udz+zdu)+\left(1+u^2z\right)du=0$

$u^3\left(1-z\right)dz+\left(2u^2z-u^2z^2+1\right)=0$

I do not know what to do next.

[Update]

Using the hint that was provided:

$\left(x+y\right)^2dx +x(x+y)dy=-(dx+dy)$

$u^2dx+ux(du-dx)=-du$

$xdx-udx-xdu+u^{-1}du=0$

$(x-u)dx+(u^{-1}-x)du=0$

Let $M(u,x)=x-u$ and $N(u,x)=u^{-1}-x$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial u}=-1$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-1$

By partial integration:

$ \displaystyle\int (x-u)dx+ \displaystyle \int \left( u^{-1}+x\right)du=0$

$2ux-x^2+2\ln\vert u\vert +\ln \vert c\vert=0$

$\ln \left[c(x+y)^2\right]=x^2-2(x+y)x$

$-\ln \left[c(x+y)^2\right]=x^2+2xy$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(x+y)^2dx+x(x+y)dy=-d(x+y)$$

For $x+y\ne0,$

$$-\dfrac{d(x+y)}{x+y}=(x+y)dx+xdy=x\ dx+y dx+x\ dy$$

$$\iff-\dfrac{d(x+y)}{x+y}=x\ dx+d(xy)$$

Now integrate both sides

Comment: Did I got the correct answer?

Comment: @BBS, Not sure why substitutions are required? We immediately get $$-\ln|x+y|=\dfrac{x^2}2+xy+K$$

Comment: Our professor wants us to apply the lesson called substitutions suggested by the equation.